# Overriding __eq__ and comparing two objects where one of the types is classname.classname

Tags: python, object

I have a class `Rational`.

```
    class Rational:
    
        def __init__(self, numerator, denominator=1):
            self.numerator = numerator
            self.denominator = denominator
    
    
    
            r1 = Rational(1, 4)
            r3 = Rational(r1)
```

I want the following to print True

```
print(r3 == r1)
```

I am struggling with the concept of `Rational(r1)`. This would give me the type `Rational.Rational`. In trying to override `__eq__`, I've tried writing:

```
def __eq__(other, x: Rational.Rational)
```

but this doesn't work. How do i make r3 copy the values of r1?

I tried changing **init** into

```
 @dispatch
 def __init__(self, x):
     self.numerator = x.numerator
     self.denominator = x.denominator
```

but this gives me "TypeError: _() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given".

And this is my current definition of **eq**:

```
  def __eq__(self, other):
        x = False
        if self.numerator == other.numerator and self.denominator == other.denominator:
            print(f"Self.numerator: {self.numerator} and Self.denominator: {self.denominator}")
            x = True
        return x
```

Comment: This looks like 2 separate questions - (i) how to define `Rational.__eq__()` and (ii)how to process if `__init__()` gets `numerator` argument other than int, e.g. another instance of Rational class (note it can get any type). How do you define equality, is Rational (1, 4) and Rational (2,8) equal?

Comment: No, I'd like them to only be equal if they hold the exact same numbers. I'm new to Python, and do not know how to write in code that if the numerator argument is another instance of the rational class, it should copy it.

Comment: You need to change the `__init__()`

Comment: I tried         @dispatch
        def __init__(self, x):
            self.numerator = x.numerator
            self.denominator = x.denominator            (sorry, don't know how to format this if commenting), but it gives me "TypeError: _() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given"

Comment: Please, don't post code/additional information in the comments. Edit your question to include all relevant information.

Comment: `Rational(r1)` does not not give you a value of `Rational.Rational` (an expression that doesn't even have a meaningful definition, as `Rational` has no class attribute named `Rational`); it gives you a `Rational` whose `numerator` attribute has type `Rational` instead of type `int` (or whatever you expect the numerator to be).

Comment: @chepner, that makes a lot more sense when I think of it that way! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
from functools import singledispatchmethod

class Rational:
    @singledispatchmethod
    def __init__(self, numerator):
        self.numerator = numerator.numerator
        self.denominator = numerator.denominator

    @__init__.register
    def _(self, numerator:int, denominator=1):
        self.numerator = numerator
        self.denominator = denominator

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Rational({self.numerator}, {self.denominator})'

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.numerator == other.numerator and self.denominator == other.denominator

r1 = Rational(1, 4)
r3 = Rational(r1)
print(r1)
print(r3)
print(r1 == r3)
```

You can use [`functools.singledispatchmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatchmethod) on `__init__` (note, requires python3.8+). Because `Rational` is not yet defined, your default implementation would be for the case when first (and only) non-self argument is instance of class `Rational`, i.e. it has `numerator` and `denominator` attributes. Then you can register another implementation for `int`. Now I leave it to you to implement it for `str`, e.g. `'1/4'`.

As per your definition, two instances of `Rational` are equal *only if they hold the exact same numbers*, i.e. `Rational(1, 4)` and `Rational(2, 8)` are not considered equal, despite 1/4 == 2/8.

Finally, let mention there is [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) module from Standard LIbrary

Answer (score 2):

Rather than try to overload `Rational.__init__` to accept two `int` values or a single `Rational`, define a class method that breaks down a `Rational` value into its `int` components to create a new `Rational`.

```
class Rational:

    def __init__(self, numerator, denominator):
        self.numerator = numerator
        self.denominator = denominator

    @classmethod
    def from_rational(cls, r: 'Rational'):
        return cls(r.numerator, r.denominator)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.numerator == other.numerator 
                and self.denominator == other.denominator)



r1 = Rational(1, 4)
r3 = Rational.from_rational(r1)
```

You'll note that with this definition, `Rational(1,2) == Rational(2,4)` will return `False`. I leave it as an exercise to modify `Rational.__init__` to modify which values you actually store to make `__eq__` work. (Rather than modifying `__eq__`, you'll want to store a "canonical" representation of the rational rather than simply storing the arguments.)

This definition also assumes duck typing: you can successfully compare any value with `numerator` and `denominator` attributes to a `Rational`. You may want to make the definition more robust (what if `other` doesn't *have* both attributes), as well as allow comparisons like `Rational(6,2) == 3` to return `True`.